# Make JSON from Image and Entered Data in forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I apologive for reposting but someone advised me to ask 1 question at a time.
My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39837815/6511388) was put on hold as anwering those 3 at once would've been very big.

*I've already check internet and Stack Overflow but i could not find that answer.*

So here's my question.

I have a project in which i'm supposed to ask a user about 30 - 40 questions or more and the user is supposed to Upload a few images as well ( about 5 - 8 ) 
So i wanted to ask , **How can i take All that data ( The images and information ) and make a JSON File with that** 
 
Also i apologise for not being able to  provide any example code of what i've tried as i dont know how to start.

Thanks everyone in advance for giving your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to add all the fields including image file upload html elements to a html page and wrap it in `<form>` tags ensuring that you have enctype="multipart/form-data" in the tag and the server php file in action attribute.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="serverside.php">....<all the fields ...</form>
```

Submit it to the serverside.php file that then iterates through all the fields and adds them to an array. Before writing the images to array, Base64 encode each image so you have a string and then add it to the array.

json_encode the whole array as you write it to your json file:

```
$fp = fopen('thefile.json', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $json_encode($myarray);
```

Comment: is there any way to test this procedure on front-end side using jQuery/Javascript ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can build and layout the form without server side script but of course not submit it and create the json file.